# PL/SQL: Count number of nodes in xml

Tags: xml, plsql, count, nodes

I am working with Oracle.

Is there a way to count the number of nodes (including descendants) within an XML file using PL/SQL?

I would like to be able to save the result as a variable to be used as an upper limit for a loop iterator.

I have the following xml, and I want to count the number of nodes within the row node:

```
<row>
  <date name="date1" id="101"></date>
  <element1 name="ele1" id="111">
    <stuff></stuff>
    <stuff></stuff>
    <stuff></stuff>
  </element1>
  <element2 name="ele2" id="121"></element2>
  <element3 name="ele3" id="131></element15>
</row>
```

The result should be 7.

@johnbk I am working with Oracle

The idea here is that after I get the number of nodes I can use it in:

```
nodeCount := 1;
    FOR i IN 1 .. numNodes
    LOOP
        xpath1 := '/row/*[' || nodeCount || ']/@name';
        SELECT EXTRACT(form_xml, xpath1) as other_name;
        nodeCount := nodeCount +1;
    END LOOP;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which database are you working on?

Comment: @johnbk I am working with Oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to be able to save the result as a variable to be used as an upper limit for a loop iterator.

I guess this is related to your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248726/pl-sql-how-to-loop-through-sql-extract-results/) ?

You don't need to know the number of nodes as your don't have to explicitly loop xml by yourself. You might be trying to solve your real problem in a suboptimal way.

Below how you can find the number you're looking for with [XMLQUERY](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions249.htm#CIHHFFGG):

```
declare
  v_data constant xmltype := xmltype('<row>
  <date name="date1" id="101"></date>
  <element1 name="ele1" id="111">
    <stuff></stuff>
    <stuff></stuff>
    <stuff></stuff>
  </element1>
  <element2 name="ele2" id="121"></element2>
  <element3 name="ele3" id="131"></element3>
  </row>');
  v_count xmltype;
begin
  select xmlquery('count($doc/row/descendant::*)'
          passing v_data as "doc"
          returning content)
    into v_count from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || v_count.getstringval);
end;
/
```

Comment: Just curious, so I can understand the language better, what would you do if I had to query to get the v_data and cannot 'declare' it?  It's coming in off a query that grabs the info from a database.  Would you SELECT table.data INTO v_data?

Comment: @quotemyname: That is one option but you can get XML data also directly from database table. This gets the XML data from table `so11t` column `xmldata` where `so11t.id = 1`:
`select xmlquery('count($doc/row/descendant::*)' passing t.xmldata as "doc" returning content)
into v_count from so11t t where id = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the [`dbms_xmldom`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmldom.htm) package

```
DECLARE
  l_doc  dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  l_list dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  l_clob clob;
BEGIN
  l_doc:=dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(form_xml);
l_list:=dbms_xmldom.getChildNodes(dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild(dbms_xmldom.MakeNode(l_doc)));
  dbms_output.put_line('length='||dbms_xmldom.getLength(l_list));
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);
END;
```

Depending on you Oracle version it can have problems with XML containing more than 64K nodes - see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=614453